# How to add flags to golang build in dockerfile

Tags: node.js, exec

I am currently running a node server with a golang submodule in docker.
To run the golang module, I run the command

```golang
go run cmd/downloader/main.go -build 1621568 -outdir /src/results
```

I have been unable to figure out how to add these flags to the golang build in my dockerfile. Here is my current dockerfile.

```
FROM golang:1.17 AS downloader
WORKDIR /app
COPY component-review-handler/ ./ 
RUN go build -o downloader ./cmd/downloader

FROM node:14
# vvv add this line
COPY --from=downloader /app/downloader /usr/local/bin/

# same as before
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

In the node service, I execute the golang binary by running

```js
exec(
    `downloader`,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        logger.error(`error: ${error.message}`)
        return
      }
      if (stderr) {
        logger.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
        return
      }
      logger.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
    }
  )
```

The issue is I need to add flags to my downloader command. Does anyone know how I can add this flag when I dynamically run the binary in the node server?

```sh
-build 1621568 -outdir /src/results
```

Comment: I don't see how this is really a Go question, or even a docker question.  Sure, you're running a Go app, but you're asking about nodejs exec.  I'm going to remove those tags.  Confident dissenters, feel free to overrule me.

Comment: Sure sorry for the bad flags. Its a node server running a go binary in docker, just wanted to be thorough. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try execFile instead

```js
execFile('downloader', ['-build', '1621568', '-outdir', '/src/results'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        logger.error(`error: ${error.message}`)
        return
      }
      if (stderr) {
        logger.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
        return
      }
      logger.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
    }
  )
```

Comment: When I try to add the flags here I get the following error
error: Command failed: downloader '-build 1621568'

flag provided but not defined: -build 1621568

Comment: Try execFile `execFile('downloader', ['-build', '1621568', '-outdir', '/src/results'], (error, stdout, stderr) => {...})`